# Parsing url from txt file

Tags: python, parsing, robots.txt

I am trying to parse a txt file which looks like this:

```
Disallow: /cyberworld/map/ # This is an infinite virtual URL space
Disallow: /tmp/ # these will soon disappear
Disallow: /foo.html
```

I need to  read the file and extract the part with the url after 'Disallow' but also ignoring the comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to parse a **robots.txt** file then you should use the [robotparser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/robotparser.html) module:

```
>>> import robotparser

>>> r = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
>>> r.set_url("http://www.your_url.com/robots.txt")
>>> r.read()
```

Then just check:

```
>>> r.can_fetch("*", "/foo.html")
False
```

Comment: That is a pretty awesome module

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there's no `#` in the URLs:

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    URLs = [line.strip().lstrip("Disallow:").split("#", 1)[0] for line in infile]
```

Allowing for the existence of `#`, but assuming that comments beginning with `#` and the urls are separated by a space:

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    URLs = [line.strip().lstrip("Disallow:").split(" #", 1)[0] for line in infile]
```